# Is there a way to securely install Nvidia GTX 1660Ti driver to fedora 32

Tags: fedora, nvidia

Need help in installing NVIDIA graphs card in fedora 32

I tried steps given [here](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/).

Downloaded *.run file from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us)

Tried both ways, manual getting error and via rpm fusion looks success but Fedora->settings->about still not showing NVIDIA option as graphics card.

Also want to make sure it's done without disabling secure boot which might compromise security.

kernel: 5.7.14-200.fc32.x86_64
Fedora : 32/ 64-bit
NVIDIA: GTX 1660 Ti

`nvidia-installer -v |grep version` says **nvidia-installer:  version 430.09**

`lspci |grep -E "VGA|3D"`
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 T

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Rpmfusion [doesn’t](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/Secure%20Boot) support secure boot.

The NVIDIA .run installed supports [signing the kernel module](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.57/README/installdriver.html#modulesigning) but you have to generate the signing key and
[enroll your own key in the firmware](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-enrolling-public-key-on-target-system.html).

Considering the latest set of boot vulnerabilities associated with secure boot, I really don’t feel that turning it off hurts you too much.

Comment: Hi installed via NVIDIA *.run file and installation failed with error 

I tried installing using NVIDIA *.run file and gettng error after disabling secure boot , then only tried rpmfusion   

> 
Error : failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidea -v 430.09 -k 5.7.14-200.fc32.x86_64`:

Kernal Preparation unnecessary for this kernal . Skipping.....



now in reboot says nvidia kernal missing going back to nouveau

Comment: guess i figured out how to come-out of the error Installed NVIDIA 440.100 (which by default never comes in NVIDIA site) 

Now stuck at fedora boot menu for long time. Looks some problem with fedora kernal version and nvidia driver version. tried nvidia 440.10, 430.09, 450.57 ntng helps in resolving the boot freeze unless i uninstall the nvidia graphics card driver by loggin into terminal from boot instead of gui

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA drivers must be signed before they can be used on EFI Secure Boot-enabled systems.

During the installation process, you will be asked to the sign the drivers with a user-specific MOK key, which has to be enrolled later into the BIOS.
There is a great Ask Ubuntu thread regarding this (I'm guessing that it'll also be useful on Fedora): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048135/how-can-i-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-secure-boot

If Fedora's `nvidia-installer` package doesn't have a built-in signing module, you might need to sign them manually using `mokutil`: https://gist.github.com/Garoe/74a0040f50ae7987885a0bebe5eda1aa